# `C-c C-c` compilation stopped working in SLIME but works if manually typed, how to fix it?

Tags: keyboard-macros, compilation, slime

I am new to Emacs and Slime. I have been using both of them daily for the last 10 days. And it is amazing! I am impressed.

Today, I decided to install and try the package [Paredit](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit). Not sure if this is a coincidence, but after a while, Slime stopped working as it used to.

I was using `C-c C-c` all the time to compile specific Common Lisp functions. Now, it does not work.

Even with slime running after pressing `M-x slime` I get from the mini-buffer:

```
C-c C-c is undefined
```

If I try a stronger compilation with `C-c C-k` the keyboard also does not work.

However, the compilation works if I manually compile the region or the whole file after typing on the mini-buffer:

```
M-x slime-compile-region

M-x slime-compile-and-load
```

Before writing this, even the manual typed compilation was not working. Suddenly, it started to work again. But the keyboard shortcut is not back.

I do not really understand this behavior from emacs/slime.

This is my current [config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-emacs-config/blob/main/.emacs).

Why is this happening? Did I break something after installing Paredit?

What should I inspect to understand why the famous commands (C-c C-c and C-c C-k) suddenly stopped working?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: If the Sly/Slime conflict from your other question resolves this be sure to come back and self answer.

Comment: @nega, sure. I would be really glad to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not mention it in my post, but after installing Paredit I also installed **Sly**, a fork from the **Slime** project. This was the root of the problem.

I learned how to uninstall packages with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541322/how-to-remove-installed-elpa-package).

In addition, @nega connected the dots between this problem and this [other](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/65022/why-this-keybinding-conflicts-message-keeps-appearing-how-can-i-fix-it) post.

After removing Sly, Slime is perfectly functioning! And the keybindings such as `C-c C-c` are working as usual.